# Can I send MMS messages with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, mms

I am trying to send an image message to cell phone like SMS. I used the PHPMailer to email the image like

```
$mail->addAddress('222222222@txt.bell.ca','');
$mail->addAddress('222222222@mms.bell.ca','');       
$mail->addAttachment('img/map.png', 'map.png');
```

This is sending the text but I am getting

```
A MIME attachment of type <image/png >was removed here by
```

instead of the image in iPhone 4. I searched the web for this and I think I must use a MMS Gateway to send the image. Is that the case?

Comment: MMS usually expects a SMIL XML format message, though it's possible your gateway might build one for you if you ask nicely.

Answer (score 0):

yes you would have to use MMS Gateway to send an image. This is because MMS is Multimedia Messaging Service and SMS is Short Messaging Service so that's you need the MMS gateway to send the image (multimedia)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks d0lmioboy but I cant find any reference on the web for Canadian MMS carriers ! There are lists of SMS providers but nothing for MMS!

Comment: Hey Mona, which carrier were you looking for, as I imagine they would use the same carrier as the SMS but don't hold me to that.

Comment: for example `bell Mobility` the `222222222@txt.bell.ca` is sending the text but not MMS

Comment: Are you certain Bell support email to MMS as this may be the case?

Comment: I am sure Rogers and Telus doing this but not sure about bell

Comment: This might be the problem then, I was recently coding an email to SMS and I couldn't find a UK carrier to support it so it didn't function. This may be the case for you.